# Excluding tables from flyway:clean

Tags: database, flyway

I am looking for a way to make a certain table, manually added and not managed by flyway impossible to drop when flyway:clean is executed.

I was looking for some solutions and the only think somehow related to that issue is http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_9015.htm but I would prefer to have a solution inside flyway tool. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not currently supported.

Comment: @AxelFontaine - When someone asks how to do something, saying that it can't or shouldn't be done is never an acceptable answer. Even if it's true, such a statement should be added as a comment to the question, not as an answer. If the question itself is illogical, it should be flagged and deleted, not have a comment pointing that out added as an "answer".

Comment: This is the only correct answer to this question. Since this question is about specifically Flyway, and I am the author of the tool, I believe I am uniquely qualified to answer it. Which I did.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create and use your table in a different schema which is not managed by flyway.